# Getting most common values using mode in excel

Tags: excel, mode

I have a list of 65 random numbers starting in column D2.
I am trying to make a new list of number in column J2 that arranges these numbers by most frequent number.

I did this by tying the below formula into j2:

```
=MODE(IF(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH($D$2:$D$66,$J$1:J1,0)),$D$2:$D$66))
```

The problem is some numbers from column D are not appearing in column J. why is this?

Comment: Because, if you test with a small range (say $D$2:$D$6 ) with the values 1,2,3,4,5  you will see that your formula is not correct. Even changing the values to 5,4,3,2,1 will give another result as earlier....

Comment: Sorting the values on the output of `RANK.EQ(...)` seems to give a better result.

Comment: @Luuk How can i use this in my specific case? i am having trouble getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With values in **D2** through **D66**, in **E2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$66,D2)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Then sort both columns by column **E** descending:

[image]

This will capture all 65 items.  If desired, you can perform a secondary sort on column **D** to cluster similar values.